# Port binding with a container in docker-py doesn't work

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I'm trying to run a container using docker-py and bind ports with the host. I'm afraid I'm not experimented with Docker, but I try many things and I can't see where my mistake is.

My docker API version is 1.22

Here is my code for create the container :

```
from docker import Client
cli = Client(base_url='tcp://172.16.3.87:2375', version='1.22')
container_id = cli.create_container( 'busybox', 'ls', name='test', ports=[1111], host_config=cli.create_host_config(port_bindings={ 1111:8000 }, publish_all_ports=True) )
print(container_id)
```

The container is created, but there is no bind :

```
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
d3ad8566958d busybox "ls" 42 seconds ago Created test
```

However, the host received the command. I captured the incoming traffic on 2375 port. Here is the result :

```
{"Tty": false, "NetworkDisabled": false, "Image": "busybox", "Cmd": ["ls"], "StdinOnce": false, "HostConfig": {"PortBindings": {"1111/tcp": [{"HostPort": "8000", "HostIp": ""}]}, "PublishAllPorts": true}, "AttachStdin": false, "MemorySwap": 0, "Memory": 0, "ExposedPorts": {"1111/tcp": {}}, "AttachStderr": true, "AttachStdout": true, "OpenStdin": false}
```

When I try to bind on the host directly, it runs without any problem.

Has someone experimented the same issue ?

Thank you by advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted creates a container. In order to bind the ports, you need to start the container.

```
from docker import Client
cli = Client(base_url='tcp://172.16.3.87:2375', version='1.22')
container_id = cli.create_container(
  'busybox',
  'ls',
  name='test',
  ports=[1111], 
  host_config=cli.create_host_config(port_bindings={ 1111:8000 }, publish_all_ports=True)
)

response = cli.start(container=container_id.get('Id'))
print(container_id)
print(response)
```

Once you start the container it should bind the ports.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but it doesn't solve the issue:

Comment: EDIT : Your solution actually works, the container needs to be started in order to bind the port. However, I needed to replace the 'ls' by 'top'. Because with busybox ls, it stops the containers instantly. Thank you for your answer